# How to find the size of a shard in solr?

Tags: solr

I can view the size of index files by logging into the solr server and navigating to the folder where solr physically stores the index files, but does solr expose any API endpoints for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core admin STATUS [command](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/coreadmin-api.html#coreadmin-status) returns the size of the index files as well in the response.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much .